# Changing cell colours of a TableLayoutPanel by variables during runtime?

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel currently with multiple rows + columns. It's populated by a for loop that will be different every time it's run dependant on the output of an SQL Query.

```
void tblTableLayoutPanel_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row == 2 || e.Row == 4)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, r);
        }
    }
```

This is the code I've got currently to colour individual rows, but I'd like to be able to colour individual cells depending on 2 variables (J, and K).

```
                TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(label, J, K);
```

Similarly here is a sample of how I've added a label to a cell in the TableLayoutPanel using J and K. Is it possible to overload the CellPaint method to allow J and K to be used in it? or if so how could I go about re-colouring cells during runtime?

I've asked this question previously and got the following solution;

> CellPaint is an event and not a method. I suggest you create a method GetColor(int row,int column) that returns a color Brush and then in the CellPaint event call your method with e.Row and e.Column.

I'm not entirely sure how this would work as the variables I am using are in the main program, wouldn't I then need to compare these with the variables in my method? or set them somewhere to be compared and then after that do the event. Could anyone explain this a bit clearer for me? or maybe give me an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
void tableLayoutPanel_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;
    g.FillRectangle(GetBrushFor(e.Row, e.Column), r);
}

private Brush GetBrushFor(int row, int column)
{
    if (row == 2 && column == 1)
        return Brushes.Red;

    // other logic
    // ...
    // return default Brush
}
```

Remark - it looks strange that you want to assign color based on just on row and column index, instead of some business logic (i.e. depending on data displayed in cell).

Comment: but if I want to make the row and columns equal the value of 2 variables I have in the form_load is that possible?

Comment: @DanBarker make those variables fields of your form class, then both will be available in GetBrushFor method

Comment: Ah yeah of course.. I don't know why I didn't realise that... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to save j and k in [Control.Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx), to example as array of objects and during cell paiting get j and k back from the control what is in this cell.